# MVC PHP Application don't work with relative urls for Codeception tests

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, model-view-controller, codeception

I have my own mvc php application that i build from scratch. All the links in my application are the absolute urls (HTML files).

I have a global variable ASSET_ROOT that i defined in my config.php file like this :

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
    define('ASSET_ROOT',
            'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .
            str_replace($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '', str_replace('\\', '/', DIR_BASE) . 'public')
    );
}
```

And i use this variable in all HTML pages (with twig templates) like this.
Example :

```
<a href="{{ ASSET_ROOT }}/user/index">Click</a>
```

So, now i want to use only relative urls like this

```
<a href="/user/index">Click</a>
```

with user is the controller and index is the method.

My .htaccess file is like this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mvc/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]
RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

The reason of my request is that i want to use codeception in my application and i can't pass my tests with absolute urls. Please help me !!

Thanks

Comment: "and i can't pass my tests with absolute urls" - presumably you mean with root-relative URLs?

Comment: No, i can't passed with absolute URLs.
it's give me this error :
[GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException] cURL error 3:  (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for http://localhost:8888c/wamp64/www/cp_test/public/client/checkout/1

Comment: Ok, that does make more sense, but it was just the way you phrased the first part of your question... "So, now i want to use only relative urls like this". So, what is stopping you from using "relative urls" (or rather, _root-relative URLs_)?

Comment: Thanks for your questions.
My mvc application works very good by the absolute URLs.
Now i installed the codeception dependency and when i run the tests. I have errors in href because it contain absolute URLs by relative URLs, the codeception work but the app no

Comment: Ok, I get that, so what's the problem with changing them to root-relative URLs?

Comment: If i change them to relative URLs, my MVC not working. I don't have a Router class to manage urls